# Swift: Use a FontAwesome icon as a UITabBarItem image

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, font-awesome, swift2

I would like to use some icons in the [FontAwesome Swift library](https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift) as UITabBarItem images. I have been able to set the UITabBarItem title, but I am not able to set the UITabBarItem image. My code is as follows:

```
class AEVTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var itemLabels = ["Promos", "Marcas", "Amigos", "Cerca de mí", "Más"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tabItems = self.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]!

        for index in 0..<itemLabels.count {
            let currentItem = tabItems[index] as UITabBarItem
            currentItem.title = itemLabels[index]
            currentItem.image = String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(FontAwesome.Money) as UIImage
        }
    }
}
```

What the compiler is telling me is that 'String' is not convertible to 'UIImage'. Is there a way to convert a String into a UIImage or is there another way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the readme on that library you linked:

```
currentItem.image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Money, , textColor: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(30, 30))
```

The function you used returns a string that is the text shortcut for the icon. This would be useful for a label or button text that's using FontAwesome. What you're trying to do is set the image - I would re-read the Readme, and just get acquainted with the built in functions of that library.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I should have read a little bit that library.